# php functions for serialization?

Tags: php, serialization

I was asked this interview question recently and I didn't know about this:

> "Which PHP functions can be used to customize the serialization
>   process of an object?"

Any sample implementation will be of great help to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly described in official documentation for `Serializable` interace - `serialize` and `unserialize` are the ones: http://php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php

The old way is to implement methods `__sleep` and `__wakeup` which were supposed to remove references to runtime resources and reinitialize them respectively. This is not supported if the class implements `Serializable` mentioned earlier.

Comment: You can still use __sleep() and __wakeup(), they are not deprecated or removed as one may get the idea from your post.   The Serializable interface just provides access to protected data.